# Check input for alphanumeric and slashes in Bash?

Tags: bash, substring

I want to check if the input contains only alphanumeric characters and `/`slashes.

My code:

```sh
if [ ! -z `echo $2 | tr -d "[\/:alnum:]"` ]; then
   echo "Error: input contains non-alphanumeric characters."
   exit 1 
fi
```

If I type `.script.sh /example/test/` an error is thrown. Why?

Comment: `if ! [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9/]+$ ]]; then echo "Error: input contains non-alphanumeric characters."; exit 1; fi`

Comment: & the reason for error being shown is probably because your $2 contains some special characters, which are treated specially by `[   ]`

Comment: The problem is on how you're using `tr` check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tr` as `tr -d '[:alnum:]\/'`

Example:

```
str="123.abc?/123#"; tr -d '[:alnum:]\/' <<<$str
.?#
```

You can see in the example above anything that's not alphanumeric nor `/` gets printed.

Using within `if`:

```
str="abc123/"; if [ -n "$(tr -d '[:alnum:]\/' <<<$str)" ];then echo invalid; else echo valid; fi
valid

str="abc123/."; if [ -n "$(tr -d '[:alnum:]\/' <<<$str)" ];then echo invalid; else echo valid; fi
invalid
```

So Your code should look like:

```
if [ -n "$(tr -d '[:alnum:]\/' <<<$2)" ]; then
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `tr`, it can be done in pure BASH:

```
if [[ ! "$2" != *[^[:alnum:]/]* ]]; then
   echo "Error: input contains non-alphanumeric characters."
   exit 1
fi
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to @kojiro this solution won't need regex:

```
if [[ ! "$2" != *[^[:alnum:]/]* ]]; then
   echo "Error: input contains non-alphanumeric characters."
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You don't need `=~` style regular expressions, either. `! [[ $2 != *[^[:alnum:]]* ]]`

Comment: Actually no. Glob doesn't provide equivalent features of regex anchors `^` and `$`. Even `[[ "1@" == *[/[:alnum:]]* ]]` will also return true.

Comment: You don't need anchors for this use case. If *`$2` does not contain any characters that are not alphanumeric*, then `$2` only contains characters that are alphanumeric. (Unless `$2` is empty, but that's an easy edge case to test out.)

Comment: You can test `[[ "a@" != *[/[:alnum:]]* ]]` is not returning true.

Comment: Note the triple negative in my original comment: *not-($2 does not match (a string containing a non-alphanum character))*. The equals sign in the expression confuses things because it's not *equality*, it's *pattern matching*. You need all three negations for this to work. The benefit is that it will work portably (using `case`) where Bash won't.

Answer (score 1):

since it fails as long as you find a single [^0-9/] or $2 is EMPTY, you can probably take the following:

```
if [[ -z "$2" || "$2" =~ [^0-9/] ]]; then
    echo "Error: input contains non-alphanumeric characters."
    exit 1 
fi
```